# iOS - Reading Facebook Posts in UITableView

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to show a Facebook page posts using UITableView. Is there a way for that in iOS 5 or 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a OAuth Token and get the JSON Feed from the OpenGraph

For the OAuth Token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<client_id here>&client_secret=<client_secret here>&grant_type=client_credentials
```

and for the feed:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<facebook_page_id>/feed/?access_token=<oauth_token>
```

You get an JSON Array back and can parse it using your favorite JSON Parser. 
In Addition you can explore the open graph using this tool:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
```

Hope that helps. Happy iCoding.